# A tutorial for designing reports in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting

Okay, I've done the following:

1. Created a blank form and added a reportviewer control to it.
2. Created a dataset, bound it to a database table.
3. Clicked the Smart Tag on the reportviewer to design a new report.
4. Chose my dataset as the datasource for the report.

After I finished the above and ran the program, I had a nice little report showing on my screen.  Great!  However, it's pretty ugly.  I want to know how to spruce it up, add charts, etc.  Is there a tutorial available online that will show a user how to get the most out of the report design tool in Visual Studio 2010? Perhaps something that takes the user from the ground up designing a report?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://gotreportviewer.com/) seems pretty extensive and has lots of images and walk throughs

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) page also seems like something you are looking for.

Comment: Well, well, well!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!  You get the checkmark as soon as the timer is up.